# PHP 5.5 Upgrade Broke this Simple Array / JSON Encoder

Tags: php, arrays, json

I just upgraded to 5.5.17 from 5.3.x and the following code stopped working (I get a blank response).

```
$gestr = mysql_query("SELECT name,age,id FROM users");
$star = array();
while($starid = mysql_fetch_array($gestr)){
     $star[] = array('name'=>$starid['name'],'age'=>$starid['age'],'id'=>$starid['id']);
}
$final=array('users'=>$star);
echo json_encode($final);
```

Please note that I have simplified the SQL statement, but I know it works all the way through the while loop because I can echo out $star[1][name] and it prints a user name.

Comment: What's exact error? Why do you think that the upgrade is the reason?

Comment: The code was working fine until yesterday... I just reran it after upgrading and I get a black page. I can append the echo statement to echo json_encode($final).$star[1][name]; and it outputs the first user's name. So the error is somewhere in the way the $final array is created.

Comment: If you wrap that into a try-catch and print out an exception, is there an exception?

Comment: what if you add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); to the top of the page code?

Comment: The likely reason is because you're using a deprecated way of connecting to a MySQL database in PHP 5.5: mysql_*. Read up on it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) and use a different method of connecting to a database.

Comment: @ChrisForrence has right, all the mysql_* function are deprecated from php 5.5.* try to learn PDO, is much much better

Comment: Like I said, I get actual data out of the DB and assigned to the $star all the way through the while loop. I understand that mysql_* functions are deprecated in 5.5, but they are not removed and these functions work for now.

Comment: No errors reported after enabling full reporting.

Comment: @0pt1m1z3 - Alright, then the next thing to check would be json_encode. Can you `var_dump($final)` and see if it has output? If it does, then you can use `json_last_error()` after the encode line to determine the exact nature of the error.

Comment: @ChrisForrence: var_dump or print_r give me the contents of $final. json_last_error() gives me "5".

Comment: @0pt1m1z3 I'm working on an answer now, but 5 is the integer error code for JSON_ERROR_UTF8. First thing to do is to check your character set coming out from MySQL

Comment: Thanks Chris, I added the answer below and cited your help. Btw, I used json_last_error_msg() which gave me "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with json_encode not being able to parse a non-UTF8 encoded name. Thanks to @ChrisForrence for suggesting using json_last_error();

The error was fixed by adding utf8_encode();

```
$star[] = array('name'=>utf8_encode($starid['name']),'age'=>$starid['age'],'id'=>$starid['id']);
```

Comment: Also have a look at those: [`mysql_client_encoding()`](http://en.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-client-encoding.php), [PHP: Character sets](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php), [UTF-8 in PHP and MySQL](http://blog.flowl.info/2014/mastering-unicodeutf-8-encoding-php/).